# In a cluster on a VM Exception encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any seeds

Tags: cassandra

Exception encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any seeds.
I have 4 VMs. I make 1st VM's IP addrease as seed to the cluster.
But when I installed cassandra on VM2 this message shows.
Actually cassandra does not starts even not taking bin/cassandra command.

Comment: Make sure all Cassandra ports are reachable for inter VM communication.

Answer (score 1):

This is because I did not off firewall.

```
 $ service iptables status
 $ service iptables save
 $ service iptables stop
```

Or we have to enable following ports:

```
 $ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9042 -j ACCEPT
 $ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7000 -j ACCEPT
 $ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7001 -j ACCEPT
 $ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7199 -j ACCEPT

 $ /etc/init.d/iptables save
 $ service iptables restart
```